# how can i fetch the activity_message value if given conditions are verified using python

Tags: python

sample data:

```
user_id = 1
project_id = 2
a = [{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "63fda80f3ab1f908c146131d"
            },
            "data": {
                "project_id": 2,
                "user_id": 1,
                "activity_message": "Success 1",
                "activity_created_on": {
                    "$date": "2023-02-28T12:30:55.652Z"
                }
            }
    },{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "63fda80f3ab1f908c146131d"
            },
            "data": {
                "project_id": 2,
                "user_id": 1,
                "activity_message": "Success 2",
                "activity_created_on": {
                    "$date": "2023-02-28T12:36:55.652Z"
                }
            }
    }]
```

I tried in this way to sort the messages based on "activity_created_on" key to get last entry first

python

```
def tags(a):
    tags = set()
    for item in a:
       if item.get('data'):
           if all([item["data"]["user_id"]==user_id, item["data"]["project_id"]==project_id]):
            q =  item["data"]["activity_message"]
            tags.add(q)
    return tags
print(tags(a))
```

Iam trying to get the output as 'last come first serve' based on "activity_created_on key".

expected output:

```
Success 2
Success 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is enough to just reverse your set before returning it, you can try this.

```
return sorted(tags, reverse=True)
```

Otherwise you could put the found date also into a tuple and then later on sort by that date and then return split up your tuple to get rid of the date.

Comment: can you please help me to fetch the data according to time based @tetris programming in another format